# JSON file data is not changing even after publishing in Azure App Service

Tags: c#, .net, json, botframework

I worked on a Bot using MS Bot framework SDK V3.0. While working on that I have some static JSON files and I have used those files(JSON Data) to get the User details. Now I have added another user details in the same JSON file and published but I was unable to access the new user details.

I have tried changing the **Copy to Output directory** option to **Copy always** but it doesn't worked. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime web pages hold the cache of old pages.
Please clear the cache of the web pages(Browsers) and try.